# Showing that if the parametrizing values $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of a Vandermonde matrix are unique then it has a non-zero determinant with the use of the FTA

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, determinant

My whole title would be: *Showing that if the parametrizing values $a_1,\dots,a_n$ of a Vandermonde matrix are unique then it has a non-zero determinant, with the use of the fundamental theorem of algebra*, but it contains too many characters.

This exercise is from the Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms by Cox, Little and O'Shea, pp. 46 ex 2. I am currently a bit confused how to conclude that the we are about to form has $n$ roots.

Let $k$ be a field and $a_1,\dots, a_n \in k$. Prove that the Vandermonde matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1&a_1&\dots&a_1^{n-1}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & a_n & \dots & a_n^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}$ has a non-zero determinant if $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are unique. I am aware that there exists an inductive proof, but to my the following hint given by the authors suggests that there is also another way to prove the claim.

> Hint: If the determinant is zero, then the columns are linearly dependent. Show that the coefﬁcients of the
> linear relation determine a polynomial of degree ≤ n − 1 which has n roots. Then use Corollary 3.

where

> Corollary 3. If k is a ﬁeld and f ∈ k[x] is a nonzero polynomial, then f has at most deg( f ) roots in k.

So suppose that there exists some $c_1,\dots,c_n \in k$ such that not all $c_i$ are zero and $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i = 0$ where $v_i$ is the $i$th column of the Vandermonde matrix. As each row has progressively a higher exponent, it follows that the rows of this sum vector correspond to a polynomial of degree at most $n - 1$.

**Question:** While I see the correspondence between the number of rows and the claimed *$n$ roots of the polynomial*, I don't really understand how the **coefficients** are to determine a polynomial of degree at most $n - 1$; aren't the coefficients the $c_1,\dots,c_n$? Even if $a_1,\dots,a_n$ were to be treated as variables, then wouldn't we just have a system of polynomials $c_na_i^{n-1} + \dots + c_2a_i + c_1 = 0$ were we would have some solutions for $a_1,\dots,a_n$? If so, what is the issue to which we ought to run into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've shown that if the determinant is zero, then there exist coefficients $c_0, \ldots, c_{n-1}$ such that the polynomial $c_0 + c_1 x + \cdots + c_{n-1} x^{n-1}$ has roots $a_1, \ldots, a_n$. Since the polynomial can have at most $n-1$ distinct roots, the $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ cannot be distinct.